# Redmine version 3.0.3 to 4.0.3 upgrade

Tags: redmine

I'm currently on a task to upgrade from Redmine 3.0.3 to Redmine 4.0.3.

I have followed these steps from http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/redmineupgrade but the current system is running a version of Ruby that is not supported by Redmine 4.0.3. I have also tried to make a new server using Turnkey Redmine and then copied over the database and configuration file, but with no luck.

Has anyone done this before and if so is there an how-to guide somewhere?

Comment: Rvm is the answer. Ruby version manager. You can install it under user account.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be more of a general 'How to deploy a Rails application' question, not really Redmine specific.

In short, [Chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) or the aforementioned [Rvm](http://rvm.io/) are the answer to all your Ruby version problems. After installing a current version of Ruby, you will have to somehow configure your Ruby server (Unicorn or mod_rails or whatever you're using) to run with that version of Ruby. How to do that really depends on what you are running and, again, is not Redmine specific but specific to that server.